# aws cloudwatch metrics - AVG over a range

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to make an average graph of the CDCLatencySource and CDCLatencyTarget of few ARNs.

CDCLatencySource are m1,m2,m3,m4

CDCLatencyTarget are m5,m6,m7,m8

So I made another row - AVG([m1,m4]) for the Source and same for the target.
But it looks like it average only the m1 & m4 and not the whole range.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to include all metrics, so for your `CDCLatencySource` it would be `AVG([m1,m2,m3,m4])`.

Similarly for `CDCLatencyTarget` the value would be `AVG([m5,m6,m7,m8])`

The functions do not accept ranges, instead they accept each metric id individually in the list that is passed into the function.

More information for metric math is available [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html) for further reading.

Comment: So if I have 50 tasks I need to specify each one?

Comment: Unfortunately yes you would need to list each one individually

Comment: If those are the only metrics on your graph, you can get the AVG of them all with AVG(Metrics())

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html):

> AVG The AVG of a single time series returns a scalar representing the average of all the data points in the metric. The AVG of **an array of time series returns** a single time series. Missing values are treated as 0.

Thus you need to provide full **array** of time series:

```
AVG([m1,m2,m3,m4])
AVG([m5,m6,m7,m8])
```